# Get category color on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories

**Theme:** Ariva

**Plugin:** [Colorful Categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/colorful-categories/)

On the homepage, how can we get the background color of each category?

The plugin developer suggests using this code:

`get_term_meta($term_id, 'cc_color', true);`

but we can't manage to make it to work…

Thank so much if you can help us.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add the `cc_color` to the term's metadata.

You can add a meta-box to your term editor to set a colour for each category which would be saved to the metadata.

`Advanced Custom Fields` is your best option (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

Once the meta is saved with the key of `cc_color` you will then me able to pull this colour for each term using the function from the OP... `get_term_meta($term_id, 'cc_color', true);`

To get this colour to into the CSS, you would need to so something like the following

```html
<div class="category" style="background-color:<?= get_term_meta($term_id, 'cc_color', true); ?>;">
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think OP needs a metabox for this. The Colorful Categories plugin they mentioned adds this functionality to their website already. It seems they just don't know how to retrieve the actual color and apply it to each category link in archive pages.

Comment: @cabrerahector Ah yeah, I somehow missed this, thanks